# I can not get the json data to display in my second UIViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession, nsurl

I have the following two functions in my first ViewController. They load a UITableView with over 300 rows. I call the loadRemoteData function inside the ViewDidLoad. Everything works fine in the first ViewController.

```
 // MARK: - parseJSON
func parseJSON(data: NSData) {
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)

        if let rootDictionary = json as? [NSObject: AnyObject], rootResults = rootDictionary["results"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] {
            for childResults in rootResults {
                if let firstName = childResults["first_name"] as? String,
                    let lastName = childResults["last_name"] as? String,
                    let bioguideId = childResults["bioguide_id"] as? String,
                    let state = childResults["state"] as? String,
                    let stateName = childResults["state_name"] as? String,
                    let title = childResults["title"] as? String,
                    let party = childResults["party"] as? String {
                    let eachLegislator = Legislator(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, bioguideId: bioguideId, state: state, stateName: stateName, title: title, party: party)
                    legislators.append(eachLegislator)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

// MARK: - Remote Data configuration
func loadRemoteData() {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = "https://somedomain.com/legislators?order=state_name__asc,last_name__asc&fields=first_name,last_name,bioguide_id"
    if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Data Task failed with error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            if let http = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, data = data {
                if http.statusCode == 200 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.parseJSON(data)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

In the second ViewController, I want to display more information about the individual listed in the cell that is tapped, for that I use a different URL such as `https://somedomain.com/legislators?bioguide_id=\"\(bioguideId)\"` which provides me with a lot more detail. (The data being requested from the JSON Dictionary is different)

The code I use in the second ViewController is just like shown above with the only difference being the URL. I can print the url coming from the previous ViewController and it is displayed in the console log but no json data is shown.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Below is the code for my second ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var bioguideId: String?
var currentLegislator: Legislator? = nil
var currentLegislatorUrl: String?
let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// MARK: - parseJSON
private func parseJSON(data: NSData) {
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)
        if let rootDictionary = json as? [NSObject: AnyObject],
            rootResults = rootDictionary["results"] as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] {
            for childResults in rootResults {
                if let firstName = childResults["first_name"] as? String,
                    let lastName = childResults["last_name"] as? String,
                    let bioguideId = childResults["bioguide_id"] as? String,
                    let state = childResults["state"] as? String,
                    let stateName = childResults["state_name"] as? String,
                    let title = childResults["title"] as? String,
                    let party = childResults["party"] as? String {
                    currentLegislator = Legislator(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, bioguideId: bioguideId, state: state, stateName: stateName, title: title, party: party)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

// MARK: - Remote Data configuration
func loadRemoteData(url: String) {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = currentLegislatorUrl
    if let url = NSURL(string: url!) {
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Data Task failed with error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            print("Success")
            if let http = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, data = data {
                if http.statusCode == 200 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.parseJSON(data)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}

func loadImage(urlString:String) {
    let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil && data != nil) {
            func display_image() {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(currentLegislatorUrl!)
    loadRemoteData(currentLegislatorUrl!)
    loadImage("https://theunitedstates.io/images/congress/225x275/\(bioguideId!).jpg")

    self.title = bioguideId
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = currentLegislator?.firstName
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Have you printed out the response from the request to make sure the app is even getting JSON back?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not getting anything back but if I use that second URL in the first view controller I can see the data. The code for both view controllers is almost identical. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You just said you are not getting anything back. That's your problem. There must be an error with the request or with the endpoint that is returning data to you. Try the URL in a web browser and make sure you are getting info back before continuing within the app.

Comment: The URL works in a browser and on my first ViewController. I'm not getting anything on the console in the second ViewController.

Comment: I added the code for my second ViewController above. The URL comes from the first ViewController. print(currentLegislatorUrl) shows the url in the console log and the url works in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adam H. His comment made me reevaluate the URL I was using and by adding additional operators, now the data is shown in my second ViewController.